# Flask-Migrate trying to migrate User model throws error

Tags: python, flask, terminal, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I added two new columns to my User model, and I want to migrate the changes. I wrote down exact notes for myself because I have done this before and it worked:

```
flask shell
from files import db
from files.models import User
```

Then, I run it and get:

```
flask db migrate -m "Message"
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I updated Flask-Migrate and everything.

Comment: Have you registered Migrate with the Flask app - [for example](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#example) ?

Comment: yes, I remember doing that awhile back... do i have to register it every time I reopen terminal / my app?

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem and i recognized that i was using "flask shell" and when i changed to terminal i solved my problem